# Best way to structure a site with media to keep it separate from the base code. ( Opinion based )

Tags: python, database, django, file, theory

I've recently have taken a new server under my wing that has an interesting installation of django on it. The previous developer mixed in the media uploads with the static content and in other modules created it's own directory on the root file level of the project. My first reaction to this was general annoyance. ( I'm a huge fan of modular development. ) However after working to 'correct,' it's raised a question.

Even though this question is tagged with django, feel free to post response according to java and asp.net.

How do you set up your static files? Do you stack everything inside a static directory or do you take the time link each modular independently?

One of my tricks for every django app I start is, in the **init**.py of said app I put the following.

```
import os
from django.conf import settings as djsettings
TEMPLATES_DIR = (os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'./templates'),)
djsettings.TEMPLATES_DIR += TEMPLATES_DIR
```

Comment: I think with static files it really depends on the context of the app in the overall website, and the sort of website you are running. With most content-based sites I've made, most of the static content is app-agnostic, and used throughout the website, so it makes no sense to bundle them with any particular app.

Also it depends if anyone else will be using your app in the future. If so, you should look at bundling the static content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think your trick is really needed (anymore).

If you use `django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader` ([docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#loader-types))
you can put a template dir in your app dir and Django will check it for your app-specific templates

And starting with Django 1.3 you can use the staticfiles app to do something similar with all your static media files. Check the docs for the [staticfiles-finders](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#staticfiles-finders)

So finally, thanks to the [collectstatic](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#collectstatic) management command, you're now able to keep your static media files modularized (for easier development and distribution), yet you still can bundle them at a centralized place once it is time to deploy and serve your project.

Answer (score 0):

Right now I'm in the habit of putting a `static` folder in each app directory containing its static files.  I keep templates in each app directory under `templates`.  I alias the `static` path when putting the app behind nginx or apache.

One thing that I'm starting to do more of is putting static files such as javascript, css, or images behind a CDN like S3.